# Dinamically tab menu created with Jquery and Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I'm creating various tab menus after an Ajax response.
When i generate the content with JQuery and append to my HTML code with the tabular menu and the tabs, the tabs aren't connected with the divs. The tabs and divs have the same data-tab (which i generate with the ajax response.
Also, the tabs with the content arent hidden.

All of this is generated after the page is loaded.

```js
                            var htmltext = '<div class="ui top attached tabular menu"><div class="active item" data-tab="first" id="first">Resumen</div><div class="item" data-tab="second" id="second">Clases</div><div class="item" data-tab="third" id="third">Objetivos de Aprendizaje</div></div>';
                            htmltext +='<div class="ui attached tab sixteen wide row segment" data-tab="first"><div class="ui five wide column"><h1>Hello</h1></div>';
                            htmltext +='<div class="ui five wide column"><h1>World</h1></div></div>';
                            $('#all-info').append(htmltext);
                            $('#all-info').append('<div class="ui attached tab sixteen wide row segment" data-tab="second"><h1>hi Again</h1></div>');
                      $('#all-info').append('<div class="ui attached tab sixteen wide row segment" data-tab="third"><h1>And Again</h1></div>');

$('.tabular.menu .item').tab();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js"></script>
<div>hi</div>
<div id="all-info"></div>
```

In the snippet seems no problem, but like i said, the append is after the page is loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: That's how `AJAX` works because of it's asynchronous nature.

Comment: i have no problem with showed data, my problem is with the tab menu and the data